# testing assertion error in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

I'm doing a test suite in python based on the code provided by selenium and i get strange assertion errors when checking for the actual page like this:

```
sel.click("link=Overview")
sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
self.assertEqual("Naaya testing - Subtitlu testare", sel.get_title())

sel.click("link=Portal properties")
sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
self.assertEqual("Naaya testing - Subtitlu testare", sel.get_title())
sel.click("link=Metadata")
sel.wait_for_page_to_load("15000")
```

Strange in this piece of code is that i get the assertion error only at the first occurence in code, after i changed the first occurence with:

```
title = sel.get_title()
self.failUnless(title == "Naaya testing - Subtitlu testare","nu sunt "
                "pe pagina principala")
```

i got rid of the error ,but i still don't get why the second assertion does not fail but the first one do ?

Comment: sel = self.selenium
sorry i forgot about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python when you use `==` operator order may make difference. Try `"Your strng" == title` and check result. Also assertEqual may check type, so correct code will be:

```
self.assertEqual("Naaya testing - Subtitlu testare", str(sel.get_title()))
```

or:

```
self.assertEqual(u"Naaya testing - Subtitlu testare", sel.get_title())
```

if selenium uses `unicode` type.